# Polymer 2.0 IE11 template with paper-button do not work together

Tags: polymer, internet-explorer-11, paper-elements

I have following snippet on my page

```
      <template is="dom-if" if="[[buttonCancel]]">
        <paper-button>
          <slot name="dialog__slot-cancel-button"></slot>
        </paper-button>
      </template>
```

In Chrome it shows well.

In IE11 the button does not show up (even though the buttonCancel is true).

```
      <template is="dom-if" if="[[buttonCancel]]">
           TEST TEST TEST
      </template>
```

shows "TEST TEST TEST" well in IE11

```
        <paper-button>
          <slot name="dialog__slot-cancel-button"></slot>
        </paper-button>
```

shows also well

The combination of those two does not :(

Did anyone else see such issue?

Answer (score 0):

This has helped:

```
      <template restamp is="dom-if" if="[[buttonCancel]]">
        <paper-button>
          <div>
            <slot name="dialog__slot-cancel-button"></slot>
          </div>
        </paper-button>
      </template>
```